# Finding pre-image of MD5 hash

Tags: hash, md5

I have the following requirement for hashing using **MD5**.

H(A,B,C,X);

Where values A,B & C are given.
However X is not given.

I would like to find out what value of X would give a hash beginning with 32 1's bits

meaning H(A,B,C,X) = Begin with 32 '1' bits

I can brute force by testing all kinds of characters of X till i get 32 '1' bits.

however is there a faster way rather than doing this?

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5271/finding-pre-image-of-md5-hash) on different SE sites please.

Comment: Closed as off topic - your cross-post on Crypto is more appropriate there.